# Doctrine adds an entity but the pk doesn't increase

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony3 and doctirne now.
I have an entity named "post" with attributes id, messages, and date. Id is the primary key. I want to add one entity in controller. Here is the code:

```html
$post = new Post();
$creationTime = time();
$post->setMessage($postMessage);
$post->setCreationdate($creationTime);
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($post);
$em.flush();
```

Everything works fine but $em.flush() didn't work, i guess it is because the attribute id of post didn't increase itself. But in the Post.php the code is ok.
I mean that the strategy IS IDENTITY.

```html
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
```

But how come?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks ok.

Use:

```
$em->flush();
```

instead of:

```
$em.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try strategy auto instead of identity and

```
$em->flush()
```

instead of

```
$em.flush()
```

Comment: For MySQL AUTO means IDENTITY, it shouldn't be a problem.